# Access production environment variables with Vite and VueJS3

Tags: docker, vue.js, vite

I have built an app which can access the `.env` and `.env.local` environment variables locally, but the variable is `undefined` in the browser console when deployed to Google Cloud Run using Docker and Artifact Registry.

A couple of points:

- The variables have the 'VITE_' prefix.
- In the browser console on `prod`, I can see `MODE: "production"` and `PROD: true`.
- I have also tried setting the environment variable in the GCloud console, to no avail.

I am accessing the variables as:
`accessToken: import.meta.env.VITE_STORYBLOK_ACCESS_TOKEN`

I presume the issue is with the Dockerfile when copying the env file, but I can't find a fix:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
COPY ./.env.production/ /
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The cloud build returns error: `COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat .env.production/: file does not exist`.

Does anyone have any advice on either fixing the Dockerfile or setting the build to get the environment variable from the deployment settings?

Comment: When you run `npm run build` , the `.env.production` file is taken. Does it exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exist. It sits in the root with the other .env files

Comment: Check again as the error indicates that `.env.production` doesn't exist or it's in `.dockerignore`

Comment: Yeah - definitely not in there:
**/__pycache__
**/.classpath
**/.DS_Store
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/DATA
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
README.md

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying to fix this, I discovered that .gitignore was stopping the .env files from being uploaded to GCloud.

> This .gcloudignore (similar to the one generated when Git files are
> present) would prevent the upload of the .gcloudignore file, the .git
> directory, and any files in ignored in the .gitignore file:
> https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Solution:

1. Create a .gcloudignore file in the root
2. **Explicitly include** the environment variables in the upload with `!.env` to upload them